# Why does the scale of an object change while rotating it?

Tags: transforms, parent

I am making a "Digipak" CD enclosure that is made of a few separate parts parented to one another.
I intend to rig it later on, but at this point I only move the parts manually (rotate them on the Y axis). That's all.
The problem is, when I rotate the cover, it's scale changes.
To go from the opened to the closed position, I rotate the "spine" portion 90° and the cover also 90°. But when I rotate the cover, it's width increases by 2,3 cm. It doesn't mater if I rotate the spine first than the cover or the other way around, when I get to the cover's rotation, it's scale changes.
I'd like to know why that happens and how can I keep it from happening.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try applying the scale first. If this doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: Thanks Chris,
The scale was applied on the cover and the parented booklet and most of the parts... but not on the "spine". That solved it.

Comment: Hi, Dehen, Glad it's fixed!  Your question is nicely constructed, I appreciate the work that's gone into it. But I think we can 'close the case' on this one. The archive already has other posts representative of this problem, and we try to avoid duplicates. Nothing personal :)